# (Phonegap app) How to pass value of input search in two pages in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a two page application, that I need to show some results.

The fist page

```
<div data-role="content">
 <!-- content -->
  <form>
    <label for="search-1">Search:</label>
    <input name="search-1" id="search-1" value="" type="search">
</form>
```

has a form with input type search. How can I take the value of this search input, and pass it to a second jQuery Mobile page in a separate html file, so I can using the value fetch data using web-service and using a list to represent the data.

Second page

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="bookListThumbs">
  //data to be added here....
  </ul>
  </div><!-- /content -->
```

Comment: SESSIONS!!!!! along with being able to do $.cookie you can also do $.session, get reading.

Comment: I am using phonegap, does that apply also with phonegap, I mean sessions ?

Comment: Possibly not, but localstorage is probably a better solution for you in that case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

It is possible to send a parameter/s from one page to another during page transition. It can be done like this:

You can pass values with changePage:

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

And read them like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index", function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

### Example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {   
                if($('#search-1').val().length > 0){
                    $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html", data : { 'input' : $('#search-1').val()}, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
                } else {
                    alert('Search input is empty!');
                }       
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pageshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
            parameter = parameters.replace("input=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form>
                <label for="search-1">Search:</label>
                <input name="search-1" id="search-1" value="" type="search">
                <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Send data to other page</a>               
            </form>     
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hej thanx allot for the sample, before I try it, does this solution also apply when using Phonegap ?

Comment: Yes of course, only blocking point here is that this version works when transiting from one html to another.

Comment: Could you maybe modify this, so it looks more like mine, with a search input instead. What I want is to get the search result in the second page, and from that use a a ajax call. Sorry I am really beginner in this

Comment: Do you have an email? I have rebuilt this example to work with your code.

Comment: `macho.service@gmail.com´ thanx that is great help I really appreciate it

Comment: I forgot in my mail, if you have more questions feel free to ask. :)